# Groovy override compareTo

Tags: groovy, dsl

I am working under DSL using Groovy categories and I need to override/overload `==` operator. It is however [known issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3364), that when class implements `Comparable`, Groovy will call `compareTo()` method for `==` operator. I'm looking for some workaround (not AST transformation) in order to make `==` do exactly what I want.

I have the following "toy" situation:

```
class Base implements Comparable<Base>{
    int a, b

    Base(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
    }

    @Override
    int compareTo(Base o) {
        return a <=> o.a //compare only a
    }
}

class BaseCategory {
    static boolean equals(Base base, o) { //complete equals
        if (o == null)
            throw new NullPointerException()
        if (o.getClass() != base.getClass())
            return false
        return base.a == o.a && base.b == o.b
    }

    static int compareTo(Base base, o) { //compatible with equals
        int c = base.a <=> o.a;
        if (c != 0)
            return c
        return base.b <=> o.b;
    }
}
```

Now when I run

```
use(BaseCategory) {
    Base a = new Base(1, 2)
    Base b = new Base(1, 3)
    println a == b
    println a <=> b
}
```

I got `true` and `0`, instead of `false` and `-1`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Your `equals` method calls your `hashCode` method directly, which is not a great idea, but may not be the problem you are concerned with.  The `hashCode` method method is just returning `2 * a` so `b` is irrelevant.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: This is just for illustration. I've edited example to make more meaningful.

Comment: i don't see a use block or a mixin, how does the category get applied here?

Comment: @NathanHughes I've corrected example

Comment: Your `compareTo` method is broken.  It ranks x > y and y > x whenever x != y.  Your `equals` method is also broken since `x.equals(null)` is supposed to return `false`, not raise a NPE.

Comment: @MikeSamuel these are minor issues which are not relevant for this "toy" example. Even if I'll implement ``equals()`` and ``compareTo()`` more carefully, the result will be the same.

Comment: @StanislavPoslavsky, maybe so, but if you haven't spent the time to obey the contract of equals and compareTo, fewer people will spend their time trying to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 5):

An old Groovy bug<sup>[[1]](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1765)[[2]](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-1888)</sup> to be fixed in 3.0. Does your use case permit encapsulation and delegation?

```
class Base implements Comparable<Base>{
    int a, b

    @Override int compareTo(Base o) {
        return a <=> o.a
    }
}

class BaseDelegate {
    @Delegate Base base

    boolean equals(o) {
        if (o == null)
            throw new NullPointerException()
        if (o.getClass() != base.getClass())
            return false
        return base.a == o.a && base.b == o.b
    }

    int compareTo(o) { 
        int c = base.a <=> o.a;
        if (c != 0)
            return c
        return base.b <=> o.b;
    }
}
```

And the tests:

```
def a = new Base(a: 1, b: 2)
def b = new Base(a: 1, b: 3)

assert (a == b) == true
assert (a <=> b) == 0


def a1 = new BaseDelegate(base: a)
def b1 = new BaseDelegate(base: b)

assert (a1 == b1) == false
assert (a1 <=> b1) == -1
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! But unfortunately, I can not do in this way: I have existing Java library with many types of objects and I need exactly to override/overload some operators without changing the library itself.

Comment: @StanislavPoslavsky I see. How does anonymous classes sound?