# Groovy == doesn't act like it should according to specification

Tags: groovy, comparison, operator-overloading

So according to [the official documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_behaviour_of_code_code) `==` behaves like `compareTo` when called on a Comparable Object.

Now I have a class like this:

```
class LargeNum implements Serializable, Comparable<BigInteger>
```

which defines the method

```
@Override
int compareTo(BigInteger o) throws NullPointerException, ClassCastException {
    println "compared"
    return compareStuff()
}
```

You'd expect this bit of code:

```
LargeNum t = new LargeNum(1)
println t == new BigInteger(1)
```

to print out "compared" and call `compareStuff`, though it doesn't. The only output I receive is: `false`

I'm genuinely confused on why this is the way it is. Overriding `equals` doesn't quite solve the problem either.

Comment: What does `compareStuff()` do and return? You are not even sending the input to that method, do you suppose your `LargeNum.compareTo` implementation is correct?

Comment: The implementation is irrelevant - the sheer fact "compared" is not being printed proves the method isn't being called. I am not wondering about the `false` I'm wondering about the fact the method isn't invoked.

Comment: Well, I see. This is indeed interesting. Seems it's a bug. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24963680/groovy-override-compareto

Comment: `compareTo` gets invoked when the call's argument is of the same type. So `largeNum1 == largeNum2` causes `compareTo` to be called. But it doesn't seem to be aware of `Comparable`'s concrete type argument (probably for good or easy to guess reasons)

Comment: Thanks for your help Ernest, I couldn't find a workaround for this, should you come up with one please do tell. I switched to using fully implemented methods now `isEqualTo` `isLargerThan`, etc.

Comment: Oh I thought you just wanted to solve the mystery. Remember, you can use the spaceship operator (`0 == (t <=> new BigInteger(1))`). That should call `compareTo`. Check this: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/#_spaceship_operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation is not clear in this case - `.compareTo(Object obj)` gets called instead of `.equals(Object obj)` if you use `==` operator between two objects of the same type `T` that implements `Comparable<T>`. In your example class `LargeNum` implements `Comparable<BigInteger>` - in this case

```
new LargeNum(1) == new LargeNum(1)
```

will call `.equals(Object obj)` method and not `.compareTo(Object obj)`.

If you implement `Comparable<LargeNum>` and you compare

```
new LargeNum(1) == new LargeNum(1)
```

the `.compareTo(Object obj)` kicks in. Consider following example:

```groovy
class LargeNum implements Comparable<LargeNum> {

  private final BigInteger number

  LargeNum(BigInteger number) {
    this.number = number
  }

  @Override
  int compareTo(LargeNum num) {
    println "compared"
    return number <=> num.number
  }
}

LargeNum num1 = new LargeNum(1)
LargeNum num2 = new LargeNum(1)

println num1 == num2
```

Running this example produces following output:

```
compared
true
```

### Can I override `==` operator with `.equals(Object obj)` method in this case?

Short answer - nope. To understand why and what happens we need to dig a little bit into the bytecode. Following part of the code:

```
LargeNum num1 = new LargeNum(1)
LargeNum num2 = new LargeNum(1)
BigInteger bigInt1 = new BigInteger(1)

println num1 == num2

println num1 == bigInt1
```

is represented as following bytecode decompiled to Java:

```
LargeNum num1 = (LargeNum)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[1].callConstructor(LargeNum.class, 1), LargeNum.class);
LargeNum num2 = (LargeNum)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[2].callConstructor(LargeNum.class, 1), LargeNum.class);
BigInteger bigInt1 = (BigInteger)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(var1[3].callConstructor(BigInteger.class, 1), BigInteger.class);
var1[4].callCurrent(this, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(num1, num2));
return var1[5].callCurrent(this, ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(num1, bigInt1));
```

It shows that `num1 == bitInt1` is actually `ScriptBytecodeAdapter.compareEqual(num1, bigInt1)`. If we take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java#L697) we will find out that this method in our case executes method:

```
DefaultTypeTransformation.compareEqual(left, right);
```

Now, if we take a look what [the implementation of this method](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L612) looks like we will find something like this:

```java
public static boolean compareEqual(Object left, Object right) {
    if (left == right) return true;
    if (left == null) return right instanceof NullObject;
    if (right == null) return left instanceof NullObject;
    if (left instanceof Comparable) {
        return compareToWithEqualityCheck(left, right, true) == 0;
    }
    // handle arrays on both sides as special case for efficiency
    Class leftClass = left.getClass();
    Class rightClass = right.getClass();
    // some other stuff here
}
```

It shows that for any `Comparable` objects following part gets executed:

```
if (left instanceof Comparable) {
    return compareToWithEqualityCheck(left, right, true) == 0;
}
```

[The implementation of this method](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/typehandling/DefaultTypeTransformation.java#L543) reveals that if two objects are the same type or they can be cast to the common type, `.compareTo(Object obj)` method gets triggered. Otherwise it just returns `-1`. And this is what happens if we try to compare `LargeNum` and `BigInteger` - there is no common denominator between these two classes so at least for Groovy they are not comparable.

I don't know if this is bug or not that there is no fallback to `.equals(Object obj)` method. Alternatively you can always call specific methods directly, for instance:

```
num1.equals(bigInt1)
```

or

```
num1.compareTo(bigInt1) // num1 <=> bigInt1
```

However I understand that this behavior of `==` operator for `Comparable` might be pretty counter intuitive and annoying. Especially if you define your class to implement `Comparable<Object>` - I would expect that any object gets passed to overridden `.compareTo(Object obj)` but it's not :/

Hope it helps.

Comment: So is there any way to override the == as well as other comparison operators for cases where you compare with an object of another class?

Comment: You can't unfortunately. When a class implements `Comparable` then Groovy always replaces `==` with a method that uses `.compareTo(Object obj)` only and it ignores `.equals(Object obj)` method. I updated the answer above with more detailed explanation.

Comment: The answer is amazing. I spent hours trying to make it work and now I see that it is kind of impossible. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

the groovy operator `==` calls method `.equals(...)`

this code works fine

```
class A {
    private final Integer i
    A(Integer i){
        this.i=i
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        println "compare $this to $o"
        return i.equals(o)
    }
    String toString(){
        return "A[i=$i]"
    }
}

def a=new A(123)
println "${a==123}"
```

result:

```
compare A[i=123] to 123
true
```

Comment: Can you perhaps comment on what the documentation says regarding `==` and `Comparable` objects as mentioned in the question? That's what the question is primarily about, I suppose...

Comment: I agree with Ernest. Whilst solely overriding `equals` does what is should, as soon as I implement `Comparable` it doesn't anymore.